# java scanner output strange if else logic errors

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

hey people greetings to you actually i m a new coder so i just wanted to know the problem in my code kindly do tell the logic as well i am unable to print the else statement there after even when entering the age as high as 20 the output is still same as that of if statement

**code**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Shivam 
{
    int age;

    void function()
    {
        if (age<=10)
        {
            System.out.println("chutiye chota h tu");
        }
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("bada ho gya saale");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int age=sc.nextInt();
        Shivam s1=new Shivam();
        s1.function();
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read about [member variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) and [local variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that as you create the instance of your custom class with `function()` method.

```
Shivam s1=new Shivam();
```

the `int age;` sets the value of `age` as default for primitive i.e `0`.

Now when you call

```
s1.function();
```

the condition

```
if (age<=10) //evaluates to true
```

---

Now, to fix this you should accept `age` as a parameter to the `function()` instead of being the field of class as:

```
public static void function(int age) {
    if (age<=10) {
       ...
    } else { 
       ...
    }
}
```

and then call the same method as

```
s1.function(age); // from inside your main method
```

Comment: @ShivamAnand If it helps, do accept an answer so that people reading this in future can find this post useful.

Comment: sorry was new did not know that thanks by the way got a new query :)
hope u might help